# Using Socket.IO and AngularJS to make Chat Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I'm trying to make a chat application which I completed on [Code School](http://www.codeschool.com) using `NodeJS, Express, and Socket.IO`. except where they used `jQuery`, I want to use `AngularJS`.

The problem that i'm having is that my `$scope.model` gets updated by an `'join'` event emitted from my server, the client listens to this event and updates the `$scope.model`... but this change doesn't effect the DOM automatically like it's supposed to.

Index.html

```
  <body ng-app="chatApp" ng-controller="ChatCtrl">

    <header class="container">
      <h1 class="page-header">Chatt App</h1>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-3">

        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li ng-repeat="user in model.onlineUsers">{{user}}</li>
        </ul>

      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-9">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()">Tester</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Vendors -->
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

    <!-- app.js -->
    <script>
      angular.module('chatApp', [])

      .controller('ChatCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.model = {
          onlineUsers: ['test'],
        };

        var socket = io.connect();

        socket.on('connect', function(data) {

          var nickname = prompt("What's your name?");
          socket.emit('join', nickname);

        });

        socket.on('join', function(onlineUsers) {

          $scope.model.onlineUsers = onlineUsers;
          console.log('model changed!');
        });

        $scope.add = function() {
          var newUser = 'tester1';

          $scope.model.onlineUsers.push(newUser);
        };

      }]);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Node.JS

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var onlineUsers = [];
// sets root
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/src'));

io.on('connect', function(client) {

  client.on('join', function(data) {

    if(data === null) {
      data = 'Nameless';
    }

    onlineUsers.push(data);
    console.log(onlineUsers);

    client.broadcast.emit('join', onlineUsers);
    client.emit('join', onlineUsers);
  });

});

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Running at 8080');
});
```

I created a test button to add another item to the `$scope.model.onlineUsers`, and then finally, the DOM updates.

There is probably a better place to put my `socket.io` listening event's besides in my `controller` but I did also using a `.run(function() {});` but this doesn't let me inject `$scope` for some reason, so i'm not sure where to put the code for the server in an Angular Project.

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.$apply()` to apply the changes to your variable? But really, if you want to manipulate DOM, it is sometimes better to use directives.

Comment: `$scope.$apply($scope.model.onlineUsers);` this actually fixed my issue. Thanks! only problem now is that Angular doesn't like duplicate strings in my Array.. but I think i can fix that by using objects or some error handling or something.

Comment: you can use `track by $index` in your loop. Keep in mind that so far my suggestions are 'resource heavy' so to speak. On the other hand, ng is not known for its performance (: but rather for being an all in one sort of tool. I do suggest taking a look into directives though.

Comment: I'm just diving into the land of server-side code after studying front-end stuff for about a year... and I started wondering about what is more efficient, using AngularJS to load the templates, or rendering templates with `NodeJS & EJS/Jade` and just sending back the HTML through a response event